# Arrange data in Excel from maximum to minimum

Tags: excel, vba, sorting

Is it possible to arrange data in Excel from maximum to minimum value? This is not a typical sort. I have a column of data which contains 1558 numbers. However, I want to select the first 38 numbers and order them from highest value to lowest value. Following this, I want to do the same for the next 38 numbers etc until all 1558 numbers are processed. Is this possible without having to highlight each 38 numbers and using the sort function 41 times?

Comment: Are you ok to use macros/vba?

Comment: @pnuts oops didn't see that :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible:  Here's a excel formula way of doing it.  The key point here is row() must start at line 1, or we have to subtract from row() before the division to get it to line 1.  the -0.01 is to ensure increments of 38 do not get moved to the next group; while ensuring the 1st record is kept in the first group.

Insert a column using formula`=ROUNDDOWN(ROW()/38-0.01,0)` and then fill down (assuming you start in cell A1.) then sort on column a, then your next column containing the numbers you want to sort max to min.

What this does is generate a column of like numbers for each group of 38, which then allows you to first sort by it ascending, then sort by your next column descending, retaining each group of 38, and sorting max to min within each group.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I know, xQbert answered this already in a simple way. Below is the funny magic formula I could do, which can do it in a go,

Considering the values are starting from A1 cell running down till whatever range (here A1558). Copy paste this formula into any other column eg: B1 and pull it down till B1558 (or any max range you have).

```
=SMALL(INDIRECT("A"&(38*(ROUNDDOWN((ROW()-1)/38,0)))+1&":"&"A"&(38*((ROUNDDOWN(ROW()/38,0)+IF(MOD(ROW(),38)=0,0,1))))),IF(ROW()>38,IF(MOD(ROW(),38)=0,38,MOD(ROW(),38)),ROW()))
```

Oh! You said larget to smallest? Change the SMALL() function to LARGE()

```
=LARGE(INDIRECT("A"&(38*(ROUNDDOWN((ROW()-1)/38,0)))+1&":"&"A"&(38*((ROUNDDOWN(ROW()/38,0)+IF(MOD(ROW(),38)=0,0,1))))),IF(ROW()>38,IF(MOD(ROW(),38)=0,38,MOD(ROW(),38)),ROW()))
```

Nothing else need to be done, you got your sorted groups as something like below.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work.  You select a specific range from C1 - C38 then sort.  Next sort C39 - C77 and so on.

```
Range("C1") = "Index"
Columns("A:C").Sort key1:=Range("C2"), _
    order1:=xlAscending, header:=xlYes
```

Source
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840646.aspx

Comment: @pnuts You just put it in a loop I believe he was saying he didn't want to highlight and sort 41 times and wanted to automate it...

Comment: This community is to help people solve their programming issues not do it for them!  The source link has a loop written in it as well, so he could look it up that way.

Answer (score 0):

A quick VBA loop should do it. Just step by 38 to sort each group. Assuming your data is in column A and starts at row 1, you could use the following:

```
Dim i As Long
For i = 1 To 1558 Step 38
    Range(Cells(i, "A"), Cells(i + 37, "A")).Sort Range("A1"), xlDescending
Next
```